# Is it really useful to abi encode your transaction input info?

Tags: solidity, web3js, web3.py

When interacting with my contract I send the input info without any encoding and can be easily extracted if anyone gets my abi.

I found out that there are private services with large abi databases to get "any" abi.

If anyone has my abi, is it really useful to implement an abi.encode-decode system in my contract?

Are there safer alternatives to encode this information and avoid bad practices with my transactions?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "I send the input info without any encoding..." ?

Comment: there is this function: abi.encode, that encodes a bunch of information into just one variable. Later in the function called I could abi.decode that information.

Comment: By default, the calldata are abi.encoded. When your solidity function is called, there is an implicit decoding done so that you can use the different parameters values. What you seem to be asking is already being done by default, it's just not explicit.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there safer alternatives to encode this information and avoid bad practices with my transactions?

On public blockchains everything, by definition, is public.

What you are asking does not exist for public blockchains. If you want to have transactions other blockchain ecosystem participants cannot see, do not use EVM based public blockchains.